# While exporting a static array sometimes returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array where I export it,
Sometimes this array returns me null, sometimes returns only the first element, sometimes all elements.

This is how I use

```
export const items= [
{
    title:"title1"
},
{
    title:"title2"
},
{
    title:"title3"
},
```

];

I use it in my app.js

```
import { items } from './data.js'
```

When I use it in useEffcet as I said, sometimes returns three elements some times just one element, and sometimes null. Thanks a lot

```
useEffet(() => {console.log(items)},[])
```

Comment: There's more to this than you've described. As you've described it, that just doesnt happen! Something else must be changing/updating `items`.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks a lot, you were right, somewhere in the project. some code was poping items out of the array. Thanks a lot